# Proving Combinatorics sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation

The original question was

> Let $S=\{1,2,3...n\}$. Find the number of unordered pairs $\{A,B\}$ such that A and B are disjoint. (Either of them or both may be empty)

I came forward with two solution $${3^n+1\over 2}$$and $${1\over2}+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk 2^{n-k-1}$$

Both of them are equal. I've check on Desmos and Geogebra. How can I show this analytically?

PS. I know how to get both the answers. Just not sure how to prove them equal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Calculate $(1+2)^n$ in two different ways.

Comment: Ahaha that was easy xD, Gonna mark it in 10 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @AnvitGarg It's easy when you've seen the trick before. That being said, showing that the two expressions count the same thing in two different ways is usually how I would go about proving an equality like this (at least when the algebraic proof is more complicated than it is this time). But if you want some confirmation that both approaches really do count the same thing (more than what computers can give you, since they are, ultimately, finite), then you would need an algebraic proof like this.

Comment: yeah, I actually wasn't sure of the second answer. I had already verified on desmos so I need a algebraic proof